# Sitecore Reporting Service How to validate setup

Tags: reporting

I have completed the Sitecore Configuration for remote Sitecore Reporting Service for my CM server. How do I validate that its correctly configured? Is there something/anything on the CM server what executes directly against the remote reporting service setup?

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that your setup is correct:

1. Verify that the following configuration files are enabled on the CM:

   - Sitecore.Xdb.Remote.Client.config
   - Sitecore.Xdb.Remote.Client.MarketingAssets.config
   - Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.RemoteClient.config
2. Open `/sitecore/admin/ShowConfig.aspx` on the CM and verify that:

   - There is a `<remote enabled="true">` node under `<reporting>`;
   - There is a `<httpTransportFactory>` node with a non-empty `serviceUrl` parameter.

If your configuration is correct, the following applications will get all data from the remote server:

- Experience Analytics
- Path Analyzer

If data is displayed in any of these applications, your setup is valid.